# 7Zip and forfiles - Invalid argument/option - 'a'

Tags: command-line, 7-zip

I need some help with a script I'm working on. It seems I'm missing something. The command line is as follows:

```
forfiles /P "F:\source_path\" /M *.bak /D -1 /C ""D:\7za\7za a -tzip -mx7 -v40m E:\destination_path\"Backup_name_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~-5,4%" F:\source_path\""
```

On execution I get:

> ERROR: Invalid argument/option - 'a'.

The "a" is only present in the 7z syntax, but the whole command is in double quotation(?!). Any help would most appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that FORFILES really doesn't like anything following /C except "/cmd /c ..."  It also doesn't like a backslash at the end of the /P argument.  You also aren't specifying any @ arguments in your /C command--that seems strange (why even use FORFILES then?--you could do this in one 7-zip command).  Finally, I think you have too many unnecessary double quotes.  Try this to see if it gets you going on the right track:

```
forfiles /P F:\source_path /M *.bak /D -1 /C "cmd /c D:\7za\7za a -tzip -mx7 -v40m E:\destination_path\Backup_name_%DATE:~7,2%_%DATE:~4,2%_%DATE:~-5,4% F:\source_path\"
```